# Error HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I am new to Spring security , i am using the example mentioned [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-limit-login-attempts-example/)
 by Mkyong, i am using the annotation based example presented on this tutorial, but it always through an exception whenever i enter value into login form and click on submit button as below.

```
type Status report

message Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

description Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.
```

I tried google it but didnt find any suitable answer, that solves this problem. the security config class is below.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationProvider")
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')").and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf();
    }

}
```

and

**login.jsp form is below**

```
<form name='loginForm'
            action="<c:url value='/login'/>" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
                </tr>       
                <tr>                
                    <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                        value="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
```

Please help me to come out from this issue.

Comment: show your web.xml in question

Answer (score 4):

Please add the below code to your security config and see if it makes any diff

```
.and()
          .csrf().disable();
```

Comment: I want to use CSRF , this error wont come if i disable csrf  and  in securityConfig and removing line <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" /> from login page.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with multipart form type, you just need to use this

```
<form name='loginForm'
            action="<c:url value='/login'/>" method='POST'>
```

instead your original below

```
<form name='loginForm'
            action="<c:url value='/login'/>" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If you need to use form type as multipart form than Add a MultipartFilter to web.xml ensuring that it is added before the Spring Security configuration:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>springMultipartFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```